# Matrix exponential via Cayley-Hamilton Theorem

Tags: matrix, replacement, linear-algebra

I'm attempting to calculate the exponential of a matrix via Cayley-Hamilton theorem. (Following the "concrete example" from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)

I am having trouble manipulating the characteristic polynomial:

```
A[1] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
cp = CharacteristicPolynomial[A[1], x]
A[2] = x^2 - cp
A[2] = A[2] /. {x -> A[1]}
```

This is the form of the example. Now, I can't figure out a way to multiply only the +2 by the identity matrix, while substituting in `x->A[1]`.
The correct result should be

```
5 A[1] + 2 *IdentityMatrix[2]
```

which obviously does not match

```
A[2] = A[2] /. {x -> A[1]}
```

As the "+2" is applied to all elements of `A[1]`, not just the diagonals.

Comment: This exact problem is solved in the [Documentation for `MatrixPower`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixPower.html), last example under *Applications*.

Comment: look at question [Verify Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79053/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To expand on David's answer, you need to replace it with the correct function. It turns out the pattern to do this is a little tricky to get right, either that or I'm out of practice. So, I'll walk you through the process using `f` as the "correct" function.

Initially, I would propose attempting to match using a default exponent, `n_.`,

```
cp /.  x^n_. :>  f[x, n]
(* -2 - 5 f[x, 1] + f[x, 2] *)
```

which as you see does not match the `x^0` term. So, it seems we need to deal with that term directly,

```
cp /.  {x^(n_.)  :>  f[x, n], c_?NumericQ :> c f[x, 0]}
(* -2 f[x, 0] - 5 f[x, 0] f[x, 1] + f[x, 2] *)
```

which is over aggressive. To tone it down, we need to add a leading coefficient,

```
cp /.  {c_. x^(n_.)  :>  c f[x, n], c_?NumericQ :> c f[x, 0]}
(* -2 f[x, 0] - 5 f[x, 1] + f[x, 2] *)
```

which we also make optional so it will match `x^2`.

Now, applying this to your exact problem, we substitute `f` for the correct function: `MatrixPower`, e.g.

```
x^2 - cp /. {c_. x^(n_.) :> c MatrixPower[A[1], n], 
   c_?NumericQ :> c MatrixPower[A[1], 0]}
(* {{7, 10}, {15, 22}} *)
```

which is the correct answer

```
MatrixPower[A[1], 2]
(* {{7, 10}, {15, 22}} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

Remember that (A[1])^2 is not the same as A[1].A[1].  So you need to recode all of the powers (greater than one) in the characteristic polynomial into the form of MatrixPowers.

Comment: The purpose of using Cayley - Hamilton is to avoid using matrix powers. So, I'm not sure how your comment relates to my problem?

Comment: @gKirkland he's absolutely correct. The distinction is `x^2` is interpreted as `Power[x, 2]`, but if `x` is a matrix, then _every_ element is squared. This helps speed up some types of calculations.

Comment: One cannot fully avoid all matrix powering, even in using Cayley-Hamilton. It allows one to write powers higher than n in terms of the powers up to n.