# Calling Integrate with many limits of integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I accidentally discovered that you can put many numbers into the limits of integration of `Integrate` and *Mathematica* will still evaluate it without returning an error message:

```
Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, 46, 53, -1, 2}]
```

returns `8/3`.  *Mathematica* seems to ignore all the numbers except for the first and last ones.  Do the middle numbers ever affect the result in some way that I haven't noticed, or are they completely irrelevant?  I don't see anything in the documentation about this.

*Update:* The same thing happens with `NIntegrate`.  `Trace` doesn't help, but it appears that *Mathematica* is evaluating each integral connecting consecutive bounds of integration in the list.  The integral takes longer to calculate when you add in extra numbers into the limits list, and

```
Integrate[1/x, {x, 1, -1, 2}]
```

returns

```
Integrate::idiv: "Integral of 1/x does not converge on {1,-1}"
```

even though the integral converges if you ignore the intermediate numbers.

*Update 2*: The behavior appears to have something to do with specifying integration contours.

```
Integrate[1/x, {x, -1, I, 1}]
```

returns `-I Pi` while

```
Integrate[1/x, {x, -1, -I, 1}]
```

returns `I Pi`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have now apparently surmised, this is actually a way to specify piecewise linear contours in the complex plane. [It's in the docs, but in a not very prominent spot.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html#436654347)

A less trivial example might be to use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) to evaluate the Fibonacci numbers, using a square contour centered at the origin:

```
Table[Integrate[z^-n/(1 - z - z^2), {z, 1/2, I/2, -1/2, -I/2, 1/2}]/(2 π I),
      {n, 5}] // FullSimplify
   {1, 1, 2, 3, 5}
```

Comment: Good eye - that's an *extremely* not-very-prominent spot ...

Comment: Also, your example doesn't really need a specified contour at all - you can just do `Table[Residue[z^-n/(1 - z - z^2), {z, 0}], {n, 5}]` :)

Comment: Yes, `Residue[]` would be the *more readable* procedure (and `SeriesCoefficient[]` the most convenient); since you were asking about `Integrate[]`, I brought out one of my usual examples. [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92504) is another one.